# Python: Adding a default function to a class?? or Class operators not sure

Tags: python

I am still learning a great deal. So go easy please. :)

I have 2 classes that everybody and there brother use at work.  I have some functionality that I would like to add.

Class 1:
foo_the_unchangeable (c code that has a python wrapper, and is the interface lib for our product)

Class 2:
foo_used_by_all

```
m=foo_the_unchangeable()
```

So when I write test scripts for our product I do thinks like

```
MyObj = foo_used_by_all()

x = MyObj.m.Item("some text showing product options").Value
z = MyObj.m.Item("some text showing product options").DisplayValue
```

or

```
MyObj.m.Item("some text showing product options").Value = 9<br>
MyObj.m.Item("some text showing product options").DisplayValue = "Mark"
```

The code I want to write is:

```
MyObj = ()

x = MyObj("some text showing product options").Value
Y = MyObj("some text showing product options").DisplayValue
```

or

```
MyObj("some text showing product options").Value = 9
MyObj("some text showing product options").DisplayValue = "Mark"
```

I am not sure what to do the class foo_used_by_all so I can write scripts the way I want. 
I was able to make a member function that returned a class. It's close; but not exactly what I want.

```
foo_used_by_all
  def Item(self, text_str)
    return self.m.Item(text_str)
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: `MyObj = ()` doesn't make any sense, maybe you should explain in words what that is trying do.

Comment: It was a typo on my part.   it was supposed to be MyObj = foo_used_by_all()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to implement the `__call__()` method:

```
class UsedByAll:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api = TheUnchangeable()

    def __call__(self, text):
        return self.api.Item(text)
```

And given the shown names, please have a look into [PEP8](https://www.pep8.org/).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
MyObj = foo_used_by_all()
MyItem = MyObj.m.Item    # or MyObj = MyObj.m.Item
```

then

```
x = MyItem("some text showing product options").Value
Y = MyItem("some text showing product options").DisplayValue
MyItem("some text showing product options").Value = 9
MyItem("some text showing product options").DisplayValue = "Mark"
```